# Can't get XML node when using namespace

Tags: c#, xml

I looked everywhere and can't read the value of an XML node that has a namespace prefix when using the namespace manager.

```
XmlDocument rssXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        rssXmlDoc.Load("https://www.kijiji.ca/rss-srp-batterie-percussion/quebec/c612l9001");

        StringBuilder rssContent = new StringBuilder();
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(rssXmlDoc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("dc", @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2005-08-25T08-37-41");
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("g-core", @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD");

        XmlNodeList rssNodes = rssXmlDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");

        // Iterate through the items in the RSS file
        foreach (XmlNode rssNode in rssNodes)
        {
            String itemsForList = "";

            XmlNode rssSubNodeTitle = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
            XmlNode rssSubNodePrice = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("g-core:price", nsmgr);
            if (rssSubNodeTitle != null && rssSubNodeTitle.InnerText != "")
            {
                itemsForList = rssSubNodeTitle.InnerText;
                if (rssSubNodePrice != null) { itemsForList += " (" + rssSubNodePrice.InnerText + ")"; }
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(itemsForList));
        }
```

Comment: Oups in fact can't get the price:   g-core:price

Comment: Please share more details and error if any

Comment: The rssSubNodePrice is always NULL :(

Answer (score 0):

The URI for the g-core namespace was wrong. It works for me when corrected to the following:

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("g-core", @"http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");
```

When debugging these things it's helpful to save the XML to a local file and examine it in Visual Studio, Code, etc.